# Springboot application property with placeholder which is updated dynamically inside app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, application.properties

Is there a way in which i can have a property in my `application.properties` file which can be holding a property with a placeholder which can later be populated inside the app?

Example (in below example {ID} is the place holder which is changed later in app):

**application.properties**

```
url.fetch.data.with.id=http://localhost:8080/data/{ID}/details
```

Which can then be used inside the application as below:

```
@Value("${url.fetch.data.with.id}")
String dataUrl;

String makeUrl(String id) {
  return dataUrl.replace("{ID}", id);
}
```

In above I use String class `replace()` function to replace `{ID}` with `id`

Are there any functionalities provided by Springboot to achieve this result where I can dynamically change a part of my property inside the app?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved easily.

```
@Value("${url.fetch.data.with.id}")
String dataUrl;

String makeUrl(String id) {
  return UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(dataUrl).buildAndExpand(id).toString();   
}
```

using the above code, if the URL has multiple placeholdets, add the values to be substituted in order.

```
url.fetch.data.with.id=http://localhost:8080/data/{ID}/details/{detailed}?startDate={startDate}&end={endDate}
```

```
long startDate = java.time.Instant.now().toEpochMilliSeconds();
long EndDate = java.time.Instant.now().toEpochMilliSeconds();
String detailedId = "abc";

String makeUrl(String id) {
  return UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(dataUrl).buildAndExpand(id,detailedId,startDate,EndDate).toString();   
}
```